# How to make a fixed layout epub file from an MS Word document?

Tags: epub, fixed-layout

We tried Adobe InDesign. We imported the `docx` file into InDesign (via Place), but InDesign hangs (freezes; not responding) on exporting to EPub Fixed Layout.

No error message is shown, what could be wrong? Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. We used the old `doc` format. Converting it to the new `docx` worked.
2. If cannot convert to `docx, create a new InDesign document, then move the previously imported pages to the new document via the Pages panel.